# Substituting Variable in sed command

Tags: variables, sed, replace

I have ./cpptest.sh to which I am passing a command line parameter
For e.g.
`$./testcps.sh /srv/repository/Software/Wind_1.0.2/`

The above command line parameter, is stored in variable $1
when I echo $1, the output is correct (the path)

Actual issue...
There is another file let's say abc.properties file. In this file there is a key-value field something like location.1=stg_area.
I want to replace the 'stg_area' with the value stored in $1 (the path) so that the substitution looks like location.1=/srv/repository/Software/Wind_1.0.2/

Now, to achieve this, I am tried all option below with sed and none worked

`sed -i "s/stg_area/$1/" /srv/ppc/abc.properties` //output is sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

`sed -i 's/stg_area/'"$1'"/' /srv/ppc/abc.properties` //output is sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unknown option to `s'

`sed -i s/stg_area/$1/ /srv/ppc/abc.properties` //output is sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

I think I have tried all possible ways... Any answer on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You know that `sed` is using `/` as a special separator in the command `s/pattern/replacement/`, right? You've used it yourself in the question.

So obviously there's a problem when you have a replacement string containing `/`, like yours does.

As the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) says:

> The `/` characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given `s` command. The `/` character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can appear in the regexp or replacement only if it is preceded by a `\` character.

So the two available solutions are:

1. use a different separator for the `s` command, such as

   ```
   s#stg_area#$1#
   ```

   (although you still need to check there are no `#` characters in the replacement string)
2. sanitize the replacement string so it doesn't contain any special characters (either `/`, or sequences like `\1`, or anything else sed treats as special), for example by escaping them with `\`

   ```
   sanitized=$(sed 's#/#\\/#g' <<< $1)
   ```

   (and then used `$sanitized` instead of `$1` your sed script)

Comment: Thanks for answering mate. I opted the second option but got the same output again sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: I have used sed command in the same way (as mentioned in question) for another replaced operation in the same file abc. properties and that works well. The another line is replacing 'stg_area' in  location.1=stg_area. Just that sed is not substituting the value of $1 into 'stg_area'

Comment: You need to echo the exact command line given to sed to see exactly what's wrong, then. Just add `set -x` towards the top of your script, it'll print everything it does, and show how all the variables are expanded

Comment: After enabling set -x I see the below problematic line ++ sed -i s/stg_area//srv/repository/Software/Wind_1.0.2// /srv/ppc/abc.properties
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: So what you're saying is that you haven't successfully applied either of my suggestions. If you had, the sed script wouldn't look like that, right?

Comment: I did apply your first suggestion of using alternate separator like # and that  worked. Although it took sometime for me to understand 'sed'.  I am  so much thankful to you :) :)